# Error in Code, unable to process based on user parameters (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I am new to Python, and working on a project for school.I need to find a similar user profile based on the dataset and user inputs. Essentially a user inputs his/her information, i would like to assign a grade and interest rate of a similar existing applicant in dataframe. However, I am failing miserably. Could somoene please help.

## loading data

```
df = pd.read_csv("LoanStats_2017Q1.csv")
df = df[["verification_status","loan_amnt", "term","grade","int_rate","dti","delinq_amnt","annual_inc", "emp_length" ]]

loan = int(input("What loan amount are you looking to obtain? "))
inc = int(input("What is your annual income? "))
dti = int(input("What is your current Debt-to-Equity Ratio (DTI)? "))

lst=[loan,inc,dti]
```

## similar user is someone within 1% of potential applicant

```
def simUser(a,b):
    return (abs(a-b)/b) <=0.01

if dti > 35:
    print('\n'+"Your Debt-to-Income Ratio is too High. Please lower it before proceeding.")

else:
    print('\n'+"analyzing..."+'\n')

#create dataframe for analysis
columns = ["loan_amnt","annual_inc","dti"]
lst1 = list(zip(lst,columns))

#go over the loan grades and interest rates
for rowNum in range(len(df)):
    lamnt = df.iloc[rowNum]['loan_amnt']
    ainc = df.iloc[rowNum]['annual_inc']
    dtiu = df.iloc[rowNum]['dti']

#scan data for similar a similar loan profile
    for user_input,col in lst1:
        lst2 = df[simUser(df.iloc[rowNum][col],user_input) == True]
```